# Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceInvalidOperationException: 'The server did not provide a response with the expected content.'

Tags: azure, linq, xamarin.forms, azure-sql-database, visual-studio-2019

I am having error while having reading table data from sql azure:

> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceInvalidOperationException: 'The server did not provide a response with the expected content.'

Following  are some images from where i am calling my database

[image: the code where i am reading data from table]

using LINQ to get table checking enter data

[image: the above image is where using LINQ to get table checking enter data]

[image]

the azure sql database table value

the application login page

just after clicking on button login having error

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Copy the code itself and format with the code format button or indent with 4 spaces

Answer (score 2):

just add following code

client = new MobileServiceClient(applicationURL, new HttpClientHandler());

for more information 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmrMg.png)

Comment: If problem solved , please mark it as answer to help others.